# Why to use Sobel/Scharr kernels for image gradient computation?

Tags: gradient, kernel

I'm confused about image gradient computation mechanism in Python. I try to find gradient  magnitude and orientation of a pixel. Here is my example image:

```
I = [[255, 255, 255],
     [0,0,0],
     [0,0,0]]
```

Now I compute vertical and horizontal gradients of the central pixel and gradient magnitude-orientation as follows:

```
Gx = 0 - 0
Gy = 0 - 255

G = math.sqrt(Gx**2 + Gy**2)
theta_rad = np.arctan2(Gy, Gx)
theta = math.degrees(theta_rad)

print(G, theta)
```

here gives correct values of `255, -90`. So far, so good. But when I try to compute this with Sobel/Scharr filters, as often advised, I get quite different values for magnitudes (direction angles are correct):

```
sobel_kernel_v = np.array([[-1, 0, 1],
                           [-2, 0, 2],
                           [-1, 0, 1]])

sobel_kernel_h = np.array([[-1, -2, -1],
                           [0, 0, 0],
                           [1, 2, 1]])

Gx = np.sum(I*sobel_kernel_v)
Gy = np.sum(I*sobel_kernel_h)
G = math.sqrt(Gx**2 + Gy**2)

print(G) # This gives 1020.0

scharr_kernel_v = np.array([[-3, 0, 3],
                           [-10, 0, 10],
                           [-3, 0, 3]])

scharr_kernel_h = np.array([[-3, -10, -3],
                           [0, 0, 0],
                           [3, 10, 3]])

Gx = np.sum(I*scharr_kernel_v)
Gy = np.sum(I*scharr_kernel_h)
G = math.sqrt(Gx**2 + Gy**2)

print(G) # This gives 4080.0
```

Actually, my question is not so far that why do I get different results (evidently, because the kernels take other neighbouring pixels into considerations as well), but why is it said that Sobel/Scharr is a "good approximation" of gradient calculation? I'd intuitively opt simply for such kernels:

```
kernel_v = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                     [-1, 0, 1],
                     [0, 0, 0]])

kernel_h = np.array([[0, -1, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 1, 0]])
```

which would exactly do the trick.

Comment: I think you may have answered your own question here: the reason why it's a good approximation due to its simplicity of implementation. You have to remember that you're working with discrete points in a matrix mimicking continuity.